# Zend\Mail fails with Gmail, but SwiftMailer lacks a file transport for development/testing. what to do?

Tags: php, swiftmailer, zend-mail

I have successfully used Zend_Mail from ZF1 to connect to a GMail account using SMTP, but have not been able to get it to work with Zend\Mail. The following produced a "Connection timed out" exception:

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

$transport = new SmtpTransport();
$options   = new SmtpOptions([
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'connection_class' => 'login',
    'connection_config' => [
        'username' => 'my_username@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'redacted',
        'port' => 587,
        'ssl' => 'tls',
    ],
]);
$transport->setOptions($options);
$message = new Message();
$message->addTo('recipient@example.org')
    ->setFrom('me@example.org')
    ->setSubject('hello, fool!')
    ->setBody("testing one two three! time is now ".date('r'));

$transport->send($message);
```

However! The very same connection parameters work fine when I do the equivalent of the above with PHP Swiftmailer, and also with Python, and also with the older Zend_Mail. All of this of course in the same environment (my Ubuntu 14.04 box). So, I think there must be an issue with Zend\Mail -- or perhaps more accurately Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.

Unfortunately I am not enough of a hero (and lack the skills) to dig into Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp and fix it, so I turned next to Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/). And it works just great,

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls');
$transport->setUsername('my_username@gmail.com')
->setPassword('redacted');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$message->setSubject("testing from Swiftmailer")
    ->setFrom("me@example.org")
    ->setTo('recipient@example.org')
    ->setBody("yadda yadda blah blah blah!");
$result = $mailer->send($message); // nice and easy!
```

but lacks one nice feature: Zend\Mail has a File transport that simply dumps your message to a file, very handy for development and testing, when you don't really want to send email messages to anyone.

What to do? I am familiar with the configuration trick of setting an "environment" environment variable to "development", "production", etc., and making my code decide how to configure itself accordingly. But in my thought experiments so far, this gets a little awkward.

One idea:  subclass Swift_Mailer and override `send()` to simply write the message to disk, and consult the $environment to decide whether to instantiate the real thing or the subclass that doesn't really send.

But I would love to hear some other ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swiftmailer you can use SpoolTransport with a FileSpool to store messages to filesystem.
[Example](https://github.com/suzuki/swiftmailer-samples/blob/master/src/270-transport-spool-file.php) (by Norio Suzuki):

```
/**
 * 270-transport-spool-file.php
 */
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once './config.php';
// POINT of this sample
$path = FILE_SPOOL_PATH;
$spool = new Swift_FileSpool($path);
$transport = Swift_SpoolTransport::newInstance($spool);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message
    ->setFrom(MAIL_FROM)
    ->setTo(MAIL_TO)
    ->setSubject('SpoolTransport (file) sample')
    ->setBody('This is a mail.')
;
// Serialized Swift_Message objects were spooled to $path
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: ah, nice! so the Swiftmailer dudes really have thought of just about everything. they just haven't yet documented it all that well, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a two-part answer and you can pick.

Answer #1:  don't worry about writing to a file, just use Swiftmailer's undocumented `Swift_NullTransport` like so:

```
$transport = new Swift_NullTransport::newInstance();
/* and so forth */
```

The `send()` method of Swift_Transport_NullTransport (parent of Swift_NullTransport) does nothing but act as though it succeeded, which in my case is about as good as dumping to a file.

Answer #2: roll your own somehow, e.g., either (a) by extending one of the Transport classes and overriding `send()`, or (b) writing another Transport whose `send()` writes to a file, and then making a PR on Github for the benefit of all sentient beings.

Comment: I un-accepted my own answer and accepted the above instead because it really answers my question, and for testing purposes I want to examine the email message body.